App center issue with Ubuntu 24.04
I got a new laptop with amd ryzen 7 7th gen processor. Installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS as fresh install. App center is showing "unable to load Check your internet connectivity". I was able to use YouTube and other site but GitHub is unreachable on browser. Could some one please help me troubleshoot the issue?

This question is similar to: App Center opens as a blank screen in 23.10. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
